# On Delete Cascade SQL

Tags: sql

The code is written as a script and when i run this script second time, is doesn't drop table `EMPLOYEE_TBL` because of which various errors are occuring.

Now the question is:  **Why doesn't `DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE_TBL` WORK?**

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE_TBL;
    DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL; 
    Create table EMPLOYEE_TBL(
      EMP_ID VARCHAR(9), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(15), 
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CITY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    STATE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    ZIP NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, 
    PHONE VARCHAR(15), 
    PAGER VARCHAR(15) );
    Alter table EMPLOYEE_TBL
    add constraints pk_EMPLOYEE_TBL primary key (EMP_ID);

     commit;

    Create table EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL (
    EMP_ID VARCHAR(9), 
    POSITION VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    DATE_HIRE DATE, 
    PAY_RATE DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL, 
    DATE_LAST_RAISE DATE, 
    Salary Decimal (4, 2), 
    Bonus Decimal (4, 2) );
    --CONSTRAINT EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID_ REFERENCES 
    --EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID)); 

    commit;
    Alter table EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL
    add constraints pk_EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL primary key (EMP_ID);


    alter table EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL
    add constraints fk_EMP_ID foreign key (EMP_ID) references EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

The second time, when you try to drop EMPLOYEE_TBL you have this constraint:

```
alter table EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL
add constraints fk_EMP_ID foreign key (EMP_ID) references EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So you must before remove this constraint and then remove the table.

For further info, please post your error

Answer (score 0):

You can't drop `TABLE EMPLOYEE_TBL` because it's referenced by `EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL`.

The `ON DELETE CASCADE` option refers to deleting *rows* in the parent table, not to dropping the parent table.

Judging by the DDL you are most probably using Oracle. In that case you can use the `cascade` keyword when dropping the table:

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE_TBL CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

The `CASCADE` option for `DROP TABLE` will automatically alsso drop all foreign keys *referencing* the table being droppen.